# googlesheet IMPORTHTML for multiple tab

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using the `IMPORTHTML` function in a Google Sheet cell to import commodities performance table from website : https://www.investing.com/commodities/real-time-futures.

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.investing.com/commodities/real-time-futures","table",1)
```

The website display `PRICE` tab by default, the `PERFORMANCE` tab must be clicked.

This formula only displays the `PRICE` tab. How can I display the `PERFORMANCE` table?

Answer (score 0):

if you click on PERFORMANCE the URL does not change - this means import formula of gs will never get to it so you can't scrape it.